# Запуск перебора ключей aircrack-ng словаря с опредленного места?

Tags: linux

Добрый день возможно я воообще не по адресу и возможно мне вобще стоит с такими вопросами идтии даааааалеко и надолго (в другой форум в смысле) если это так то зарание извините тогда вопрос мой даже стоит удалить от сюдова.

Но все же если можно то вопрос таков - в Kali Linux (бывший Back trck) есть команда aicrack-ng - запускает перебор ключей из указанного словаря, проблема в том что если словарь к примеру из 3х миллиардов комбинаций то перебираться весь он может сутками на пролет (зависит от мощности железа) - вопрос - можно ли запустить перебор словаря с определенного места - что бы время от времени отключать процесс что бы машинка отдохнула и запускать с места на котором остановили?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

К сожалению встроенных функций у aircrack-ng нет для этого, но можно установить John The Ripper, чтобы сохранять сессию на определенном моменте времени.

```
sudo apt-get install john
```

А дальше по [этой](http://www.shellhacks.com/ru/Kak-Priostanovit-Vozobnovit-Aircrack-ng) или любой другой инструкции действовать, останавливать\восстанавливать сессию перебора в любой момент времени.